# github workflow for React app with multiple jobs dont share artefact and fail

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions

I am trying to build a github workflow for a small react app.

All I am doing is `npm install && build` `npm run test` and `deploy` to gh-pages. I had this working when all of the steps were in on single job.

But i decided to split each step into a new job, and the workflow fails as soon as it is trying to run test job. I belief this is because each job is running in a separate box and once one job is finished the next job does not get the artifact and fails with:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/repo/project/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I have done some reading and found that there are gh actions that upload and download artifacts:

```
actions/download-artifact@v3
actions/download-artifact@v3
```

but i need to specify what to upload and i am not sure what i tried uploading whole build and packet.json but still fails.

My workflow:

```
name: Project name

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Install and build
        run: npm install && npm run build

      - name: Upload build artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build-artifact
          path: build

  unit-tests:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Download build artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build-artifact

      - name: Run Tests
        run: npm run test:watch

      - name: Upload test artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test-artifact
          path: build

  deploy:
    needs: unit-tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Download test artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test-artifact

      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          folder: build
```

Comment: Note: see if [upload-artifact v4](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-12-14-github-actions-artifacts-v4-is-now-generally-available/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that each job runs in a separate runner environment, and artifacts are not automatically shared between jobs.
You are correct that you can use [`actions/upload-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [`actions/download-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) to share artifacts between jobs, but you will also need to consider dependencies like `node_modules` and `package.json` that are required for each job to execute.

In your `build` job, you should upload all necessary files for subsequent jobs to function correctly. That generally includes the `build` directory, `node_modules`, and your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.

```yaml
# Previous steps
- name: Upload build artifact
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
  with:
    name: build-artifact
    path: |
      build
      node_modules
      package.json
      package-lock.json
```

In each of the subsequent jobs (`unit-tests`, `deploy`), you will need to download the artifacts uploaded in the `build` job.

```yaml
# Previous steps
- name: Download build artifact
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
  with:
    name: build-artifact
```

If you are uploading `node_modules`, you might not need this step, but it is generally good practice to ensure you are running the correct Node.js version.

```yaml
# Previous steps
- name: Set up Node.js
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: '18' # Replace with your project's required Node.js version
```

That would be:

```yaml
name: Project name

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Install and build
      run: npm install && npm run build

    - name: Upload build artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: build-artifact
        path: |
          build
          node_modules
          package.json
          package-lock.json

  unit-tests:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Download build artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: build-artifact

    - name: Run Tests
      run: npm run test

  deploy:
    needs: unit-tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Download build artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: build-artifact

    - name: Deploy
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
      with:
        folder: build
```